# How to use jar generated in war sub module (say A) as dependency of another sub module (say B) in multi module maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi module project structure like this

```
  +-- parent
     +--- pom.xml
     +--- sub-Module-A (generates A.war & A.jar)
                 +-- pom.xml
     +--- sub-Module-B (uses jar from sub-module A)
                 +-- pom.xml
     +--- sub-Module-C
                 +-- pom.xml
```

Now, in this type of setup I need to use jar generated from sub-Module-A  as dependency of sub-Module-B

any help appreciated thanks

one approach I know is to create another sub-module-D which creates A.jar and use it as dependency in sub-Modules A & B.

is it possible to solve this without creating new sub-modules

Comment: Can't we directly access the classes from the module A   into module B... as both are the child modules of the same parent... Why do you want to add it as a dependency...??

Comment: @JayanandRaghuwanshi how do you access without mentioning it as dependency? any example would be good

Comment: Try this...
<project>
  <modules>
    <module>../mywarproject</module>
    <module>../myejbproject</module>
  </modules>
</project>

Comment: above info given by you will be in parent's pom file.  if module B  is dependent on classes in module A then you need to give it as dependency in module B's pom.xml file

Comment: How do you generate the `A.jar` in sub-Module-A ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do,

```
 +-- parent
 +--- pom.xml
      <groupId>com.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 +--- sub-Module-A (generates A.war & A.jar)
             +-- pom.xml
                <groupId>com.group</groupId>
                <artifactId>parent.A</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 +--- sub-Module-B (uses jar from sub-module A)
             +-- pom.xml
                <groupId>com.group</groupId>
                <artifactId>parent.B</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

                 <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                       <groupId>com.group</groupId>             
                       <artifactId>parent.A</artifactId>
                       < version>${project.version}</version>
                    </dependency>  
                 <dependencies> 

 +--- sub-Module-C
             +-- pom.xml
```

Comment: sub-Module-A is a war project. So, we cannot give it as a dependency.

Comment: You mentioned that it generates A.war & also A.jar